# AWS Cloudwatch Metric Filter Pattern For Numbers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am having logs from my NATS docker container. Here is an example of the log.

Maximum NATS message processing delay: 50 ms...

Here is what I am trying to do. First of all, this log is not in JSON format.I am trying to trigger an alarm if the processing delay is more than 5000 ms.

I am using the filter as [(w1="Maximum NATS message processing delay: 5*" )] but as you might guess, it will just give if the delay starts with 5. I have tried different methods but haven't been able to solve it.

Thanks for your help.